# heap usage for CPS vs non-CPS parsers in Haskell's parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, heap-memory, parsec, continuation-passing

I'm trying to write the following parser using [parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec):

```
manyLength
  :: forall s u m a.
     Monad m
  => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m Int
manyLength p = go 0
  where
    go :: Int -> ParsecT s u m Int
    go !i = (p *> go (i + 1)) <|> pure i
```

This is like the [`many`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:many) function, but instead of returning `[a]`, it
returns the number of times `Parser a` succeeds.

This works, but I can't seem to make it run in constant heap space. This makes
sense, since the recursive call to `go` is not in the tail-call position.

If parsec would export the constructor to [`ParsecT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/src/Text.Parsec.Prim.html#ParsecT), it would be possible to
rewrite `manyLength` in CPS'ed form. This is very similar to the [`manyAccum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/src/Text.Parsec.Prim.html#manyAccum)
function:

```
manyLengthCPS :: forall s u m a. ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m Int
manyLengthCPS p = ParsecT f
  where
    f
      :: forall b.
         State s u
      -> (Int -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) -- consumed ok
      -> (ParseError -> m b)                     -- consumed err
      -> (Int -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) -- empty ok
      -> (ParseError -> m b)                     -- empty err
      -> m b
    f s cok cerr eok _ =
      let walk :: Int -> a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b
          walk !i _ s' _ =
            unParser p s'
              (walk $ i + 1)            -- consumed-ok
              cerr                      -- consumed-err
              manyLengthCPSErr          -- empty-ok
              (\e -> cok (i + 1) s' e)  -- empty-err
      in unParser p s (walk 0) cerr manyLengthCPSErr (\e -> eok 0 s e)
    {-# INLINE f #-}

manyLengthCPSErr :: Monad m => m a
manyLengthCPSErr =
  fail "manyLengthCPS can't be used on parser that accepts empty input"
```

This `manyLengthCPS` function *does* run in constant heap space.

Here is the `ParsecT` constructor just for completeness:

```
newtype ParsecT s u m a = ParsecT
  { unParser
      :: forall b .
         State s u
      -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) -- consumed ok
      -> (ParseError -> m b)                   -- consumed err
      -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) -- empty ok
      -> (ParseError -> m b)                   -- empty err
      -> m b
  }
```

I also tried to turn `manyLengthCPS` directly into a non-CPS'ed function using
the low-level [`mkPT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v:mkPT) function:

```
manyLengthLowLevel
  :: forall s u m a.
     Monad m
  => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m Int
manyLengthLowLevel p = mkPT f
  where
    f :: State s u -> m (Consumed (m (Reply s u Int)))
    f parseState = do
      consumed <- runParsecT p parseState
      case consumed of
        Empty mReply -> do
          reply <- mReply
          case reply of
            Ok _ _ _ -> manyLengthErr
            Error parseErr -> pure . Empty . pure $ Ok 0 parseState parseErr
        Consumed mReply -> do
          reply <- mReply
          case reply of
            Ok a newState parseErr -> walk 0 a newState parseErr
            Error parseErr -> pure . Consumed . pure $ Error parseErr
      where
        walk
          :: Int
          -> a
          -> State s u
          -> ParseError
          -> m (Consumed (m (Reply s u Int)))
        walk !i _ parseState' _ = do
          consumed <- runParsecT p parseState'
          case consumed of
            Empty mReply -> do
              reply <- mReply
              case reply of
                Ok _ _ _ -> manyLengthErr
                Error parseErr ->
                  pure . Consumed . pure $ Ok (i + 1) parseState' parseErr
            Consumed mReply -> do
              reply <- mReply
              case reply of
                Ok a newState parseErr -> walk (i + 1) a newState parseErr
                Error parseErr -> pure . Consumed . pure $ Error parseErr

manyLengthErr :: Monad m => m a
manyLengthErr =
  fail "manyLengthLowLevel can't be used on parser that accepts empty input"
```

Just like `manyLength`, `manyLengthLowLevel` doesn't run in constant heap space.

---

Is it possible to write `manyLength` so it runs in constant heap space even
without writing it in CPS-style? If not, why not? Is there some fundamental
reason that it is possible in CPS-style but not in non-CPS-style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This runs in constant heap space. The idea is to first try `p`, and explicitly perform case analysis on the result of its success to decide whether to run `go` or not, so that `go` ends up in tail call position.

```
manyLength
  :: Monad m
  => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m Int
manyLength p = go 0
  where
    go :: Int -> ParsecT s u m Int
    go !i = do
      success <- (p *> pure True) <|> pure False
      if success then go (i+1) else pure i
```

Comment: It seems like `go` should desurgar as `go !i = (p *> pure True) <|> pure False >>= \success -> if success then go (i+1) else pure i`.  This makes it look like `go` is still not in the tail call position, since it is used in an argument to the bind operator.  How does this end up working?

Comment: I am not sure about the details, but I guess the rough idea is that `<|>` attaches a continuation `pure i` which somehow doesn't get discarded as soon as the left operand consumes some input, whereas with `>>=`, when the right operand is applied to a boolean, it immediately gets reduced to either `go (i+1)` or `pure i`.