# how to tell whether Parsec parser uses constant heap space in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, heap-memory, tail-recursion, parsec

In a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092461/heap-usage-for-cps-vs-non-cps-parsers-in-haskells-parsec), I asked about the following
[parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) parser:

```
manyLength
  :: forall s u m a. ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m Int
manyLength p = go 0
  where
    go :: Int -> ParsecT s u m Int
    go !i = (p *> go (i + 1)) <|> pure i
```

This function is similar to [`many`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v:many).  However, instead of returning `[a]`, it
returns the number of times it was able to successfully run `p`.

This works well, except for one problem.  It doesn't run in constant heap
space.

In the linked question, [Li-yao
Xia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094097/3040129) gives an alternative way of
writing `manyLength` that uses constant heap space:

```
manyLengthConstantHeap
  :: forall s u m a. ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m Int
manyLengthConstantHeap p = go 0
  where
    go :: Int -> ParsecT s u m Int
    go !i =
      ((p *> pure True) <|> pure False) >>=
        \success -> if success then go (i+1) else pure i
```

This is a significant improvement, but I don't understand why
`manyLengthConstantHeap` uses constant heap space, while my original `manyLength` doesn't.

If you inline `(<|>)` in `manyLength`, it looks somewhat like this:

```
manyLengthInline
  :: forall s u m a. Monad m => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m Int
manyLengthInline p = go 0
  where
    go :: Int -> ParsecT s u m Int
    go !i =
      ParsecT $ \s cok cerr eok eerr ->
        let meerr :: ParserError -> m b
            meerr err =
              let neok :: Int -> State s u -> ParserError -> m b
                  neok y s' err' = eok y s' (mergeError err err')
                  neerr :: ParserError -> m b
                  neerr err' = eerr $ mergeError err err'
              in unParser (pure i) s cok cerr neok neerr
        in unParser (p *> go (i + 1)) s cok cerr eok meerr
```

If you inline `(>>=)` in `manyLengthConstantHeap`, it looks somewhat like this:

```
manyLengthConstantHeapInline
  :: forall s u m a. Monad m => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m Int
manyLengthConstantHeapInline p = go 0
  where
    go :: Int -> ParsecT s u m Int
    go !i =
      ParsecT $ \s cok cerr eok eerr ->
        let mcok :: Bool -> State s u -> ParserError -> m b
            mcok success s' err =
                let peok :: Int -> State s u -> ParserError -> m b
                    peok int s'' err' = cok int s'' (mergeError err err')
                    peerr :: ParserError -> m b
                    peerr err' = cerr (mergeError err err')
                in unParser
                    (if success then go (i + 1) else pure i)
                    s'
                    cok
                    cerr
                    peok
                    peerr
            meok :: Bool -> State s u -> ParserError -> m b
            meok success s' err =
                let peok :: Int -> State s u -> ParserError -> m b
                    peok int s'' err' = eok int s'' (mergeError err err')
                    peerr :: ParserError -> m b
                    peerr err' = eerr (mergeError err err')
                in unParser
                    (if success then go (i + 1) else pure i)
                    s'
                    cok
                    pcerr
                    peok
                    peerr
        in unParser ((p *> pure True) <|> pure False) s mcok cerr meok eerr
```

Here is the ParsecT constructor for completeness:

```
newtype ParsecT s u m a = ParsecT
  { unParser
      :: forall b .
         State s u
      -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) -- consumed ok
      -> (ParseError -> m b)                   -- consumed err
      -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) -- empty ok
      -> (ParseError -> m b)                   -- empty err
      -> m b
  }
```

---

Why does `manyLengthConstantHeap` run with constant heap space, while
`manyLength` does not?  It doesn't look like the recursive call to `go` is in
the tail-call position for either `manyLengthConstantHeap` or `manyLength`.

When writing parsec parsers in the future, how can I *know the space
requirements for a given parser*?  How did Li-yao Xia know that
`manyLengthConstantHeap` would be okay?

I don't feel like I have any confidence in predicting which parsers will use a
lot of memory on a large input.

Is there an easy way to figure out whether a given function will be
tail-recursive in Haskell without running it?  Or better yet, without compiling
it?

Comment: Tail recursion isn't necessary or sufficient for haskell code to run in constant space.

Comment: @Carl That's interesting, thanks.  Would you be able to add an answer explaining it?  Or maybe point me to a paper or blog post explaining it?